# Column calculations causing all 0 as result... Causes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am doing calculations on a couple of columns to get a result in a new column.

The calculations are as follows:

```
[% Free] = SUM((((((fS.freespace)*8)/1024))/(((fS.size)*8)/1024))*100)
```

I am new to sql so this is a good chance for me to get input from experts...

So my question is, what can cause the result of this type of column to be all 0?
Could it be caused by mixed datatypes (in this case both are ints, more for my curiosity and understanding)? Aggregate function? Order of which operations are done?

Any advice, tips or input is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be cause by mixed data types.  Try this instead:

```
[% Free] = SUM((((((cast(fS.freespace as float))*8)/1024))/(((cast(fS.size as float))*8)/1024))*100)
```

Comment: It worked, thank you! Could you explain why it wouldnt work with what i had so i understand (im a student). Both data types were ints. And I did a similar calculation with two bigints and it worked.

Comment: I believe SQL kept your data in the int data type as it went through the arthimetic.  Any decimals were truncated and the result would have been some decimal * 100, but since that decimal = 0 (because the decimal was truncated) it ended up being 0 * 100 = 0.  Make sense?

Comment: A simpler way to describe the problem is that SQL Server does integer arithmetic.  So, 99/100 = 0.